# asp.net core 2 :string array parameter of controller , accepting radio button values from view , causing out of bound exception

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

In my view, I have following groups of radio buttons.

```
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="OffDay[0]" id ="1MON1" value="1MON1" />Fullday
  <input type="radio" name="OffDay[0]" id ="1MON2" value="1MON2" />Half-1
  <input type="radio" name="OffDay[0]" id ="1MON3" value="1MON3" />Half-2
</div>

<div>                         
  <input type="radio" name="OffDay[1]" id ="1TUE1" value="1TUE1" />Fullday
  <input type="radio" name="OffDay[1]" id ="1TUE2" value="1TUE2" />Half-1
  <input type="radio" name="OffDay[1]" id ="1TUE3" value="1TUE3" />Half-2
</div>
```

And this continues to up to 35 groups.

I receive the checked values of radio buttons from each group in the controller using a string array.

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Test(string [] OffDay)
 {
    string a = OffDay[0];// Actually I use a loop. 
    string b = OffDay[1];
   ........
   ........ //like wise.

 }
```

Problem is that If i do not select any values in the first radio button group, the array wont get initialised. Out of range exception error is shown. Similarly if I select a radio button in the first group and then select an intermediate group, the array will get initialised only for the first group. i.e for OffDay[0] only. I cant access - say for eg: OffDay[5].

Comment: What an awful way to generate a view - use a view model and strongly bind to it using TagHelpers (and it will be about 1/20th of your current code). But if your want this, then add a hidden input in each group for the collection indexer - `<input name="OffDay.Index" value = "0" />`, `<input name="OffDay.Index" value = "1" />` etc

Comment: hi stephen, I m totally new to this. I read some articles on viewmodel and got some feel of the concept. I will try it that way. Thanks for the help.